# Checking if an array of package.json dependency is sorted in alphanumeric order in typeScript

Tags: typescript, bazel, bazel-rules, bazel-rules-nodejs

I want to check if an array of package.json dependencies and devDependencies are sorted in alphanumeric order in typeScript. If it is not sorted then it should return the dep name which is falling out of place.

I want to build a bazel rule checking in typesScript to check

```js
{
  dependencies: {
    "dep2": "0.0.1",
    "dep1": "0.0.2"
  },
  devDependencies: {
    "devdep1": "0.0.1",
    "devde": "0.0.1"
  }
}
```

to return false saying dep2, devdep1 are violating.

Comment: is there any point of case sensitive sorting? I think, No

Comment: I'm just wanting to know is it sorted or not irrespective of case.

Answer (score 1):

You can compare strings using `<`, `>`, `<=`,`>=`

In a loop, if each left side value is less, it is ascending order.
So,

1. Import you `package.json` file,
2. parse it using `JSON.parse()`,
3. access object, loop through to compare values like below

```js
function check(data) {
  for (let i = 0; i < data.length - 1; i++) {
    if (data[i] > data[i + 1]) {
      console.log(false)
      return false;
    }
  }
  console.log(true)
  return true;
}

const data = ['a', 'a-b', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
check(data)

const data1 = ['a', 'c', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
check(data1)
```